# How will Dash Symbol(-) work on Laravel Route?

Tags: laravel, routes

I made the simple Route like the following

```
Route::get('{id}-side-hustles', function ($id) {
    echo $id;
});
```

so above my code worked correctly for http://127.0.0.1:8000/abebooks-side-hustles
but it didn't work correctly for http://127.0.0.1:8000/vacation-home-rentals-side-hustles

for fixing this issue, I changed the code like this

```
Route::get('{id}side-hustles', function ($id) {
    echo $id;
});
```

as you see, **'{id}-side-hustles'** didn't work. but **'{id}side-hustles'** did work.
the working doesn't have the dash symbol(-), but the not working has the dash symbol(-).

I am not sure how dash symbol (-) will work.

Comment: Problem is not on `-` symbol, The main reason why it's not work is that your refer `-` symbol as argument, you r doing something like `function example(vaction-home){}` and of course it's not allowed in php, change your `-` as `_`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [problem with dash character in the Laravel routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63146837/problem-with-dash-character-in-the-laravel-routing)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use the `Route::get('something/{id}-side-hustles', 'controller@action');` why don't you use a "slug"?

```
Route::get('something/{slug}', 'controller@action');
```

And inside your controller you would handle the logic to extract the id based on the string.

For example:

```
public function action(string $slug) : array {
    $id = explode('-', $slug)[0] ?? null;

    // (...) rest of your logic
}
```