# problem with dash character in the Laravel routing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I have this code in my route:

```
Route::get('/{lang}/post/{id}-{slug?}',function($lang, $id, $slug=null) {
    dd($lang, $id, $slug);
})->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

site.com/en/post/30             -> Work

site.com/en/post/30-myslug      -> Work

**site.com/en/post/30-          -> 404**

Why I get a 404 error? slug is optional.

If I replace the dash with another character for example 'i'

```
Route::get('/{lang}/post/{id}i{slug?}',function($lang, $id, $slug=null) {
    dd($lang, $id, $slug);
})->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

**site.com/en/post/30i Work**

Is there any limitation for the dash character?

**Laravel 5.8**

Sincerely

Comment: The problem is that if after a route parameter comes one of these characters: `/,;.:-_~+*=@|,` you can't use it inside that route parameter because Laravel adjusts the regex to exclude that parameter.

Comment: @STA, Thanks for your inf, I solve the problem by adding a regex to slug!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix it by adding this to my route:

```
->where('slug', '(.*)');
```

Now, site.com/en/post/30- Work.